# Add authorization with img src"" in ionic v3

Tags: ionic3

Using ionic v3 for android and ios development.
I have an api which gives response as a file(image), and it requires an authorization token as well. How to add header in

`<img src="api-path-here">`

is there a way to provide authorization token as header.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add attach to http client calls in header, something like this in header. In browser you will see like this -> Authorization: Bearer 75042d7f0703a614e280212ff3ada4a9a437

And also please check this below link 
https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

And please provide your sample to get better understand.